# How to save a file to a shared folder in a server via WPF and C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Copy file on a network shared drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432213/copy-file-on-a-network-shared-drive)
>   [Access a Remote Directory from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433570/access-a-remote-directory-from-c-sharp)
>   [How to pass credentials during writting file at server path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415980/how-to-pass-credentials-during-writting-file-at-server-path)

How do I save a file into a shared folder of a server from my WPF and C# application. I have the IP and the credentials of the server and have given Read/Write permission to the shared folder.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
            WindowsIdentity identity = new WindowsIdentity(username, password);
            WindowsImpersonationContext context = identity.Impersonate();

            try
            {
                File.Copy(@"d:\MyFile.txt", @"\\1.2.3.4\CopyData\Myfile.txt", true);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {                    
                context.Undo();
            }
```

Getting the following exception :

**"The name provided is not a properly formed account name."**

Comment: Please show the code to save the file.

Comment: what is the server name try running `PING -A 1.2.3.4` what is the real server name or IPAddress..?

Comment: the server is up and running and pingable. I can easily login with the credentials onto the server. The folder too has the read and write permission for the user.

Comment: suprising... all jumped for closing the question... but no one has the solution !

Comment: Are you in a domain?  What syntax do you use for username?

Comment: The second param in WindowsIdentity constractor is not a password - https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0dsd0tkz(v=vs.110).aspx